# How do I resume an interrupted video stream recording?

Tags: wireless, video, webcam, vlc

I'm trying to start a recording every evening, starting from 19:00 and stopping at 02:00. The webcam does export its stream as `rtsp` video stream and I am able to start the recording correctly with VLC using this:

```
filename="/path/to/video-`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.mp4"
length=25200
cvlc rtsp://192.168.2.186/play2.sdp\
    --sout="#std{access=file,mux=ps,dst=$filename}"\
    --run-time=$length\
    --play-and-exit
```

For some reason it sometimes loses the connection (my guess is the WiFi is blocked). No matter how hard I try I can't get vlc to reconnect and just continue writing to the file where it left off. Any pointers to what I should be looking into?